# iPhone check location services

Tags: iphone, gps, location

I have an app with location services. If I disable location services in preferences, I  check this state with this method: `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`
This method return if are all location services enabled or disabled. But problem is that I don't know, how to check state of location service for my app. I mean state when are all location services enabled and disabled is only my app ? How can I check this ? `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` not working here ... Thanks a lot ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in my code, and it work fine

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ) 
{
    //do something
}
else 
{
    //display an alert for example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns the application’s authorization status for using location services.

```
+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus
```

Return Value

A value indicating whether the application is authorized to use location services.